# How to Bulk insert 10's of Millions of Json objects into Realm?

Tags: android, realm, zip

My current Android application is an offline reference database.

The database I am using is Realm.

The process I follow to load the realm database is as follows

1). Download a zip file containing my raw data (file contents consist of a json array)

2). Persist the file to internal storage

3). Read the zip file (without unzipping) and "stream" into inMemory() Realm using

```
realm.createAllFromJson(Data.class, inputStream);
```

4). copy the inMemory() Realm to a disk based Realm with

```
memoryRealm.writeCopyTo(diskFile);
```

This works fine for a json array with 15Million objects

However I require between 25 to 40 Million objects in my production version.

The process fails for 20Million objects while "streamimg" the json array into the inMemory() Realm.

The code I use is as follows:-

```
final Realm memoryRealm = Realm.getInstance(REALM_CONFIGURATION.IN_MEMORY.getRealmConfiguration());

final File diskFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/test-data.zip");
final ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(diskFile);

for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    final ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();

    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {

        try (final InputStream inputStream = zip.getInputStream(entry)) {
            memoryRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
                try {
                    realm.createAllFromJson(Code.class, inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "execute: ", e1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My app just closes and the logcat doesnt show much detail other than this (my app : com.research.reference.database)

```
02-01 14:28:47.480 883-938/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.estrongs.android.pop
PID: 15848
Reason: executing service com.estrongs.android.pop/com.android.apps.pros.LocalMService
Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    CPU usage from 296122ms to 0ms ago (2018-02-01 14:23:51.192 to 2018-02-01 14:28:47.315):
    108% 15148/com.research.reference.database: 106% user + 2.5% kernel / faults: 793345 minor
    68% 15848/com.estrongs.android.pop: 65% user + 3% kernel / faults: 1248171 minor
    24% 13727/com.metago.astro:remote: 22% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 15561 minor 3 major
```

and this

```
02-01 14:33:39.995 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/14864/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.011 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/14864/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.027 479-479/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: attemptIncStrongHandle(56): Not supported
02-01 14:33:40.136 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16000/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.142 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16000/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.148 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15932/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.153 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16127/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.153 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/14735/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.153 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15932/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.185 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16517/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.185 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/13774/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.185 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16127/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.214 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16517/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.214 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/13774/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.214 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16127/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.259 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/16127/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-01 14:33:40.260 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/13744/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.260 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16517/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.260 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16097/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.260 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15932/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.265 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16517/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.265 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/16457/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-01 14:33:40.265 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16097/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.266 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15932/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.281 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16097/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.290 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/16097/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-01 14:33:40.304 683-683/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/16097/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-01 14:33:40.422 883-1227/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '33ae07f com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-01 14:33:41.148 883-1227/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '35729f1 com.research.reference.database/com.research.reference.database.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

How can I break up my bulk insert so that I can insert all zipped json objects?

UPDATE

This process runs in its own thread

```
 final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                try {
                    writeToMemory();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "realming: ", e);
                }

                copyMemoryToDisk();

            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

Comment: if you're running this transaction on the UI thread, then you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am running this entire process in its own  thread.

Comment: Just an assumption, but it could help to split the insertion into multiple transactions. Not sure how Realm is working internally, but I would not be surprised if they accumulate data for the transaction in memory before flushing it to the disc.

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev, how would I go about splitting my inputstream up? My zip file contains a Json array. The array contains 20 million json objects and realm accepts an inputstream. I didnt want to do any json parsing myself as that consumes more memory. unless I could use Jackson to accept the input stream and uses its streaming json parser somehow...

Comment: You might want to keep the transactions to batches of 100.000

Comment: @Hector wait, I just realised that you are reading everything into in-memory realm. Why not directly to on-disk realm?

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev, when I wrote directly to disk the persistent realm grew rapidly. By testing I found that by writing to memory first it was quicker and when I wrote the memory to disk the disk realm was compacted already.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, how would I batch to 100,000? with an inputstream input?

Comment: By creating multiple files each holding 5,000,000 records and zipping to one download file I was able insert 30,000,000.